# What is the Intuition behind the GAN Discriminator loss? How does Discriminator loss works?

Tags: neural-networks, loss-functions, generative-models, gan

I have just stated learning GAN and the loss used are different for same problems in same tutorial. Could someone please tell me **intutively** that which loss function is doing what?

For example, in the [blog by Jason Brownlee on GAN losses](https://machinelearningmastery.com/generative-adversarial-network-loss-functions/), he has talked about many loss functions but said that **Discriminator loss is always the same**. So he says that it is `maximize log D(x) + log(1 – D(G(z)))`  which is equal to saying `minimize y_true * -log(y_predicted) + (1 – y_true) * -log(1 – y_predicted)`.

What I got from this that the **D**, which is a CNN classifier would get the Original images and the Fake images generated by the Generator and tries to classify it whether it is a real or fake [0,1]. But What I don't get is that instead of using a single neuron with `sigmoid` and `binary crossentropy` , why do we use the equation given above? I mean how is that supposed to be working? What is the difference is this one making?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Discriminator loss is always the same

I think you're misreading the contex here. The two training schemes proposed by one particular paper used the same discriminator loss, but there are certainly many more different discriminator losses out there.

> What I don't get is that instead of using a single neuron with sigmoid
> and binary crossentropy , why do we use the equation given above?

It *is* binary cross-entropy. I think you're confusing the mathematical description -- "we want to find the optimal function $D$ which maximizes...", versus the implementation side "we choose $D$ to be a neural network, and use sigmoid activation on the last layer". Although the mathematical description can be very suggestive about how to implement, and vice versa, they can be written differently without any conflict.

Comment: So if I'm trying to build something like a Denoising GAN, which loss should I choose?

Comment: i'm partial to wgan-gp (with wasserstein distance loss). i've also had good results with spectral gan (using hinge loss). ultimately, the question of which gan / which loss to use has to be settled empirically -- just try out a few and see which works best

Comment: Yeah but I read one paper and they said that if other things are put constant, almost all of other losses give you same results in the end. Be it Wassertein, No-Saturation or RMS. I think I'll stick with either Wessertein or simple Log loss